# how to timeout promises in jest?

Tags: asynchronous, promise, async-await, timeout, jestjs

so I am trying to create a simple time out promise

```js
const delay = (time, value) => {
  return Promise.resolve(); //  THIS WORKS

  // NEED TO, but wont work
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(value), time);
  });
};


const request = (count) => {
  if (count === 15) return;
  return makeRequest().then(
    res => Promise.resolve() // if it works it works.
  ).catch(
    err => delay(1000).then(() => request(count - 1));
  )
}

describe("on fail", () => {
  beforeEach(() => jest.useFakeTimers());
  it("should retry 15 times", async () => {

    request();
    jest.runTimersToTime(15001); // alias `advanceTimersByTime`
    await expect(request.mock.calls.length).toBe(15); // what am i missing? or rather, what's jest missing?
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently impossible. Two things need to happen in order for this to be possible:

- From the Jest side - they need to finish [migrating to lolex](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5165) which is an ongoing effort to unify their fake timers with Sinon's
- From the Node.js side - we need to [implement hooks](https://github.com/nodejs/promise-use-cases/issues/26) that let you run the promise microtask queue yourself. This is really new work from a meeting between Node.js core and the V8 team last week.

As these two aren't yet possible - it is impossible to do what you're asking for at the moment. We're working on this though. You have to make the test asynchronous and `await` the promise - it will take 15 milliseconds and there is nothing that can be done about it.

This is because promises always delay a microtick - we codeified this in Node.js as [use case testing #1](https://github.com/nodejs/promise-use-cases/blob/master/use-cases/testing/testing-1/testing-1.md).

Comment: thank you so much for the resopnse though, I've been fiddling all night yesterday, was bout to go into the source code today, could you keep this one updated if a solution does come up?

Comment: or if theres a thread that you can share with us here would be great too!

Comment: The action item thread in the Node.js repo I opened or the one in the lolex repo work as tracking issues. I'm going to try to address this from the Node.js side after the world cup ends (which will incur work pressure) - my plan is to expose the hooks. At the moment if you're feeling "frisky" you can run node with `--allow-natives-syntax` and call `%RunMicrotasks()` to "pump" async functions.

Comment: Hello, is this still the case in August 2020? The first issue is closed, presumably fixed. The second issue is closed because of some archived project.

Comment: You can work around it using an undocumented API but probably shouldn't - the first bit happened (Yay) so fake timers now detect nextTick but we don't give you an official way to 'pump' - just make your tests async I guess.